# pausing d flip flop output

Tags: timer, multiplexer, counter, 7segmentdisplay, decoder

I want to make a digital timer that counts to 99 minutes 59 seconds the problem is that i want to use 4 digit 7 segment display so i have to oscillate the input of the bcd to 7 segment display between the four digits so i have to control the decade counter 74160 so i use mux to choose which counter to work and counter 5 oscillate switches the mux quickly . How to control f/f wheather to output or to keep the output for itself for now till it`s turn? [image: This is a quick schematic for the criteria]

Comment: Why don't you use a sim tool like micro-cap (free) and work this out yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with minimal changes to your design, consider using a *tri-state buffers* at the output of each counter.

This is a buffer with an `EN`able pin. When the enable pin is asserted, the buffer produces an output like normal. When the enable pin is de-asserted, the buffer puts its outputs in high-impedance (or high-Z) state. This not only means there's no output, it also means the output won't interfere with other gates trying to produce outputs onto the same wires.

For example, consider [74LS244](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls245.pdf). This has two sets of 4 tri-state buffers, with each set of 4 controlled by a common enable pin. Note the enable pin is active-low, so "asserted" means a low voltage and "de-asserted" means a high voltage. You'd need two of these to complete your design.